# Php Redirection To Parent Page

Tags: php, html

I have an Html site.In that there have form for sending mail in Each page.The form action is done in another page that is process.php page.I want to redirect from php page to html page after sending mail.
This is my html code

```
 <form name="mail" id="mail" method="post" action="process.php" onSubmit="return valid_form();">
  <div class="form_bg11">
   <div class="free_call_back">Free Callback Request</div>
    <input name="txtname" id="txtname" type="text" class="free_cal_field" value="Your Name" onClick="(this.value='')" >
     <input name="txtphone" id="txtphone" type="text" class="free_cal_field" value="Your Phone Number" onClick="(this.value='')">
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" style="background-image: url('images/submit.png'); border: 0px none; height: 19px; margin-left: 85px; width: 56px; margin-top:5px;" value=" ">
     </div>
     </form>
```

Thi is my process.php page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['txtname'];
    $phone = $_POST['txtphone'];

    $to = "mariyadavis90@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New Request Come !";
    $message = '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 0 20px;width: 400px;"> 
<div style="width:400px;">

<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="width:300px; text-align:center;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">
Now you got a new request from :
</div>
</div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> Name:</div>
<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">'.$name.'</div>
</div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
<!--end of div_form_main-->
<div style="width:400px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">
<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"> Phone Number:</div>
<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">'.$phone.'</div></div> <!--end of div_form_main-->
</div> <!--end of div_password_main-->';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
    if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        $msg = "Sending mail is failed  !";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Mail send Successfully  !";
    }
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    print "alert('".$msg."')";
    print "</script>";  
}
?>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: header("Location: __URL__"); will do the trick. make sure no output is sent to the browser before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your wording. Why can't you just use the PHP `header()` function?

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: by using this i cant to go the corresponding html page. Tthe process.php is common for all html page.so writing this " header('Location: http://www.example.com/');" only redirects to the site's index page not for the corresponding html page

Comment: How are you using `process.php`? Have you thought about AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

A quick write up

```
    if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            $msg = "Sending mail is failed  !";

        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Mail send Successfully  !";
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        print "window.location.href= 'www.example.com' ";
        print "</script>";  

}
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        print "alert('".$msg."')";
        print "</script>";
```

Comment: We prefer that you don't use a signature on SO. Your profile bio section can house links.

Comment: sorry i dont have much idea on that , pleas guide me on that

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your procss.php (in your javascript block)

```
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
print "alert('".$msg."')";
print "window.location.href='http://www.yourdomain/yourhtmlpage.html'";
print "</script>";
```

Comment: hey you dont think , even after the message failed it will redirect